# Laravel Eloquent form datetime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using laravel 5.2 and eloquent
Have a mysql field hiredate set to datetime type. Passing the hiredate in queryparamaters of the url. It's not getting saved in the mysql table  if i have the below way in the controller

```
**$hmHire->HireDate=$request->input('hiredate');**
```

When I log the request parameter  it shows the correct format in laravel logs

```
[2016-08-07 03:17:38] local.INFO: --------store:'2016-08-01 14:45:00'
```

But when I try the below way of hard coding the date it stores in the table

```
$hmHire->HireDate="2016-08-01 14:45:00";
```

Could any one help me out regarding this.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot send date in this format via URL

Comment: can you show your generated url ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use php `Carbon` class to convert your requested date time before saving. like this

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controller\AppController;

class YourController extends AppController {

     public function method(Request $request)
     {
          $hireDate = $request->get('hiredate');
          $hmHire = new Model;
          $hmHire->HireDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $hireDate)
          $hmHire->save();
     }
}
```

**Note:** field in database should be `datetime` datatype.

This will help you.. you can use this.